# Azure Function triggered by Queue times out regularly

Tags: java, azure

I have a linux Azure Function that is triggered by a Queue. Most messages that the Function attempts to process end up in the 'poison' queue and the only logs I can see indicate that it timed out.

```
2023-06-12 20:00:14.132  Executing 'Functions.Drone' (Reason='New queue message detected on 'drone-input-queue'.', Id=6e66d069-0b09-4966-92dd-d63a8f9aa3fc)  Information
2023-06-12 20:00:14.133  Trigger Details: MessageId: 3c54e04a-3d96-4ab9-ab69-3101f77a16f1, DequeueCount: 1, InsertionTime: 2023-06-12T20:00:10.000+00:00  Information
2023-06-12 20:10:14.133  Timeout value of 00:10:00 exceeded by function 'Functions.Drone' (Id: '6e66d069-0b09-4966-92dd-d63a8f9aa3fc'). Initiating cancellation.  Error
2023-06-12 20:10:14.133  Executed '{functionName}' ({status}, Id={invocationId}, Duration={executionDuration}ms)  Error
2023-06-12 20:10:14.133  Executed 'Functions.Drone' (Failed, Id=6e66d069-0b09-4966-92dd-d63a8f9aa3fc, Duration=600000ms)  Error
2023-06-12 20:10:14.133  Error
```

Potentially relevant information:

- The Function App is using a Consumption plan.  I know there can be cold starts, but I see this happen, like, 90% of the time, even when messages are coming in every few minutes.
- The Function App and Queue are set up using an ARM template. The Function is later deployed from an archive.
- The Function is using Linux as the OS type and is running Java code.
- I do occasionally see proper execution, so 'AzureWebJobsStorage', 'STORAGE_QUEUE_CONNECTION_STRING', and 'WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING' should all be set correctly.
- I've double and triple checked the host.json and function.json, but here they are, for reference:
  host.json

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "functionTimeout": "00:10:00",
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[2.*, 3.0.0)"
  },
  "extensions": {
    "queues": {
      "maxPollingInterval": "00:00:02",
      "visibilityTimeout" : "00:00:30",
      "batchSize": 16,
      "maxDequeueCount": 3,
      "newBatchThreshold": 8
    }
  }
}
```

function.json

```
{
  "scriptFile" : "../my.package.drone.jar",
  "entryPoint" : "my.package.Drone.run",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "message",
      "type": "queueTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "queueName": "catapult-drone-input-queue"
    },
    {
      "name": "output",
      "type": "queue",
      "direction": "out",
      "queueName": "catapult-drone-output-queue"
    }
  ]
}
```

- I was initially deploying the Function with an outdated version of the CLI.  While updating that fixed some issued, it did not fix this one.  Here is the version info.

```
# az version
{
  "azure-cli": "2.39.0",
  "azure-cli-core": "2.39.0",
  "azure-cli-telemetry": "1.0.6",
  "extensions": {}
}
```

```
# func
...
Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       3.0.4899 Commit hash: N/A  (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 3.17.0.0
...
```

I suspect it might have something to do with the scaling configuration, but am at a loss for how to configure that.  Any advice would be appreciated.

---

Here is a snippet of the entrypoint code:

```
@FunctionName("Drone")
public void run(@QueueTrigger(name = "message", queueName = "drone-input-queue") String message, 
                @QueueOutput(name = "output", queueName = "drone-output-queue") OutputBinding<String> output,
                final ExecutionContext context) {
    String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    logger.setContext(context); //custom tool for logging to context logger and/or blob
    logger.info("["+id+"] Start");
    encryption = initializeInFlightEncryptionClient(logger);
    logger.info("["+id+"] encryption initialized");
    jsonSigner = initializeJsonSigningUtility(logger);
    logger.info("["+id+"] jsonSigner initialized");
    try {
        // ... logic to handle message ...
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        logger.severe("ERROR: "+e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    finally {
        logger.closeLogFile();
    }
}
```

I forgot to mention that I have fairly extensive logging in this part of the code, so I know that, at the very least, it isn't getting past 'logger.setContext', which only sets a private variable to context.getLogger(). That's why I didn't bother sharing code earlier.
Also, I have seen messsages that take only 30 seconds to process cause this timeout. If I send like 10 of them at once, the first may get processed correctly and quickly, but the next 9 tend to all have this timeout. That's why I suspect something wonky with the configuration.

P.S. This is the ONLY Function in the Function App.

Comment: Your function simply can not process message within 10 minutes. What does it do exactly? Could you post function code (JSON is useless in this case, it's just some metadata, not the actual function's code).

Comment: I've added a snippet of the function's code and some reasoning as to why I don't think the problem lies there.

Comment: What is your `logger`? Is it some singleton? Does it use locks, or something like that? It looks like you have deadlock.

Comment: It is actually as singleton, but initialized like ```private static AzureDroneLogger logger = AzureDroneLogger.getInstance();```. Not quite how singletons are supposed to work, I suppose.  But ```logger.setContext``` only sets a private variable and the only synchronization is in the constructor.

Comment: Just for verification sake, I'd recommend to comment out all logger usage in this function, and run it multiple times. Because if it is singletone, and code does not always passes `logger.setContext` - logger might be an issue. Just check if there are timeouts without logger usage.

Comment: I'll give that a shot, as well.  Interestingly, setting ```FUNCTIONS_WORKER_PROCESS_COUNT = 2``` in the App Settings seems to have helped significantly.  Not sure its a complete solution, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research and following some of the leads provided by the comments and other answers, I found setting `FUNCTIONS_WORKER_PROCESS_COUNT = 2` in the App Settings resulted in the issue almost completely disappearing - to the point it wasn't an issue anymore.  Whether this is a good solution or not, I don't know, but that is my results thus far.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is talking longer than 10 minutes to complete. Ho wlong does it talk to complete locally? When run locally, you can set the timeout to a larger value.

If it just takes too long, your options are:

- App plan (no limits)
- Break it up into smaller pieces
- Use durable functions

Comment: I forgot to mention that a message that normally takes 30 seconds to process might time out at other times.  The duration depends on the size and nature of the message.

Comment: But did it timeout at 10 minutes? The reason why you're actually timing out might be a   whole other issue to chase down. But the error you're getting from the function is the 10 minute timeout.

Comment: Yes, it did timeout at 10 minutes.  Unfortunately, I never really tested the function locally, only in deployment.  Oddly enough, setting 'FUNCTIONS_WORKER_PROCESS_COUNT = 2' in the App Settings caused the issue to disappear almost entirely.  Not sure exactly what's going on, but by now I've been moved to another project so I won't be dealing with this issue again for some time.  I would appreciate insights to add to my knowledge base for later.